# Material data-table na horizontal

Tags: angular

Tenho um json que retorna a estrutura de dados abaixo, onde eu populo um data-table.

```
    {TimeStamp: "2019-08-07T03:30:00.000Z", Value: "377.5", Quality: 3}
    {TimeStamp: "2019-08-07T03:40:00.000Z", Value: "362.5", Quality: 3}
    {TimeStamp: "2019-08-07T03:50:00.000Z", Value: "367.5", Quality: 3}
    {TimeStamp: "2019-08-07T04:00:00.000Z", Value: "345", Quality: 3}
    {TimeStamp: "2019-08-07T04:10:00.000Z", Value: "347.5", Quality: 3}
```

Está tudo funcionando normalmente com a tabela formatada conforme abaixo.

[image: Tabela dados]

O problema é que agora preciso inverter a tabela para trabalhar com uma pesquisa de vários dias, ou seja eu teria o várias colunas sendo uma para cada dia.

Algo como:

[image: nova tabela]

Existe a possibilidade de usar o data-table ou terei que usar html puro?

Comment: Não ficou clara sua dúvida, qual o problema da tabela do material, seu problema é popular a tabela com o json?

Comment: Acho que não expliquei direito, a dúvida está em mudar a orientação, eu precisaria agrupar os valores por dia e criar dinamicamente uma coluna para cada dia com seus respectivos registros abaixo.

Comment: Man sei lá, isso tá meio estranho, vai ter uma coluna para cada dia, ou seja, vão ter de 30 a 31 colunas nessa tabela, imaginou como isso via ficar ruim. Na imagem que colocou tem 6 colunas , agora imagina essas 6 colunas multiplicadas por mais 5 colunas pra dar as 30 colunas, e no mobile, acho que não vai rolar isso dessa forma aí não, dá uma repensada aí.

Comment: De fato, apresentar uma tabela com 30 colunas não faz tanto sentido. Talvez fosse melhor usar uma tabela com paginação. Aí você mostraria apenas 1 dia, com duas colunas, e deixaria a opção do usuário clicar no próximo dia ou escolher um dia específico.

Comment: Realmente fica estranho, na verdade a pesquisa será limitada a 10 dais e não teremos acesso mobile...